# Java - Error while trying to get some Properties

Tags: java, properties

Well, I never thought I would ever need to get this far when programming, but I'm stuck..

I'm building some sort of engine for something I need to build, and I'm getting an "Expected" error..

It drives me crazy since all the source is correct (at least i think so).

Source:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Configurations {

    // Storing the file locations in Strings.
    public static String MOVE_FILE = "./configs/movement.properties";


    // Creating the needed variables for working-out stuff.
    public static String HELLO_WORLD;


    // Reading certain properties file and getting parameters.
    Properties Props = new Properties(); // Asks me to put { { here..
    try {
        Props.load(new FileInputStream(MOVE_FILE));
        HELLO_WORLD = Props.getProperty("MSG", "HelloWorld");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

} // tells me to put }; } here..
```

Comment: The above code doesn't compile. Is that the problem? What is the expected error you get? I'm sure it contains a helpful message. Reading it could be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Put statements in method body or *static* block.

```
public void methodName()
{
  Properties Props = new Properties();
    try {
        Props.load(new FileInputStream(MOVE_FILE));
        HELLO_WORLD = Props.getProperty("MSG", "HelloWorld");
        System.out.println(HELLO_WORLD);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Or

```
  static
   {
    ...
   }
```

Comment: but how do i get to echo out the HELLO_WORLD string?

Comment: `System.out.println(HELLO_WORLD);`

Comment: when i System.out.println(Configurations.HELLO_WORLD); it returns null

Comment: May be *MSG* key is not *in* *movement.properties*.

Comment: it is. maybe is there an error in the url i entered in the string MOVE_FILE?

Comment: No, if you entered wrong url then it should throw IOException. So that means your MSG key is not there .

Comment: ok now i got it. i had to declare the Reading() void in the main function. So i have Configurations.Reading(); System.out.println(Configurations.HELLO_WORLD); Thanks for the help sir :)